# Linq2Sql not updating NVarchar(Max) field?

Tags: sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql, .net-4.0

I have the folowing code to fetch a record and update one column which is of type NVarchar(Max) using Linq2Sql.

```
using (var context = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                var entity = context.Entity.Where(d => d.ID == 12).Single();
                entity.EmailTemplate = "Test Template";
                context.SubmitChanges();
            }
```

What is wrong here? I am using Linq2Sql, .Net 4 and Sql Server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has your entity got a primary key?